# Get Electron production window to load a route with loadURL?

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-builder

I've managed to build my react/electron app and have it run locally. However, the 'default' route for my app is `/app`, so when my app runs locally, nothing shows up. This is what I have:

public/main.js:

```
function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    show: true,
    frame: false,
    transparent: true,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      preload: `${__dirname}/preload.js`,
    },
  });
  const startURL = isDev
    ? "http://localhost:3000/app"
    : `file://${path.join(__dirname, "../build/index.html")}`;

  mainWindow.loadURL(startURL);

  mainWindow.once("ready-to-show", () => {
    // mainWindow.show()
    mainWindow.setSize();
  });
  mainWindow.on("closed", () => {
    mainWindow = null;
  });
}
app.on("ready", createWindow);
```

src/index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route path="/app" exact component={App} />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I'm using react-router to make this work. This does work locally, just not in production. To test this, I changed `path="/app"` to `path="/"` and removed `exact`, built it, and it worked as expected. However, I do want this to point at that particular `/app` route, since I want other unrelated windows to be at other endpoints. How do I get the build to recognise this properly? I've tried changing `homepage: "./"` to `homepage: "./app"` in `package.json` but that didn't change anything.

EDIT: I did try changing the startURL to `file://${path.join(__dirname, "../build/index.html#/app")}` (adding the `#/app`, as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58092777/how-to-route-in-electron-react-app-during-production)) but that didn't work either...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out there's two parts to this answer; the first one was a typo. Instead of `#/app`, adding `#app` is correct (so the full string becomes `file://${path.join(__dirname, "../build/index.html#app")}`).

The other issue is related to react-router-dom and the `BrowserRouter` apparently; it doesn't work in production. So instead I have this:

```
if (!process.env.NODE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route path="/app" exact component={App} />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById("root")
  );
} else {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <HashRouter>
        <Route path="/app" exact component={App} />
      </HashRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById("root")
  );
}
```

The `HashRouter` doesn't work in dev, hence the necessity of this code.